# fcitx only uses Default keyboard layout and not the current language's (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, japanese, fcitx, hebrew

I want to install a Japanese keyboard along with English and Hebrew ones. Up until now I had English and Hebrew keyboards set up through the OS settings, but a Japanese keyboard converted the English letters into Japanese letters only on the search application bar and the run bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

Not having found the solution for that (found exactly 1 thread that didn't help) I tried to use `fcitx`, but having it enabled and switching to Hebrew in the system language caused the UI to freeze (the cursor could be moved but was stuck in the same mode it was on when switching).

My last option was to try and install Hebrew on `fcitx` itself, however it seems that `fcitx` only writes in the language that's set up under `Keyboard layout to use when no input window`, no matter what application I'm in. If it's set to English both English and Hebrew write in English, while Japanese writes in English and turns it into Japanese (as expected), while if it's set to Hebrew all 3 languages just write in Hebrew.

I tried to look up a `fcitx-table-hebrew` package but it doesn't seem to exits, so that might be the problem, but it CAN write when it's set up in `Keyboard layout to use when no input window`, so I doubt that's really it.

Anyone has any clue as to how to fix any of the problems here? (honestly either one would be fine since I don't need more than one fixed in order to write in all languages)

Comment: Try `fcitx5-mozc`or `ibus-mozc`. `fcitx` like input method cannot work without an engine such as `mozc` or `anthy`.